# read resolved date using jira 4r api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jira

I am working on ruby 1.9.3. I am facing problem in fetching the issue resolved date through ruby code using jira 4R api . I am able to read the jira issues through filter number. Can any one tell me the method to read resolved date of jira issues ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get resolved date from Jirasoap gem.

ex: `resolved_date= jiraobject.resolution_date_for_issue_with_key issue_key`

make sure of dependencies while installing gem.